# IDirect3D9::CreateDevice causes FPU exception

Tags: exception, directx, directx-9, fpu

When I call IDirect3D9::CreateDevice I get FPU exception and my app crashes ("floating point division by zero").

It happens since latest update of Windows 10 (April 2018) and laptops with dual graphics (NVIDIA + Intel).

We found a te﻿mporary solution - globally disable all FPU exceptions in our app by calling Set8087CW($133F) when our app is started.

I'm sure that our code which works with DirectX is correct and there is no mistakes in parameters which I pass to CreateDevice(). Also I pass D3DCREATE_FPU_PRESERVE flag to CreateDevice().

This problem didn't happen with any previous version of Windows 10 or with Windows 8/7/Vista/XP. Also this problem doesn't occur if manually choose Intel video card for our app instead of NVIDIA.

Our app is written on Delphi (Pascal).

Comment: So what is the call stack of this exceptions? Which parameters are you using to create device?

Comment: It is likely a bug in the NVIDIA driver then. The callstack would help track it down.

Comment: Thanks for your replies.
We use Delphi and it's difficult to check where exactly the exception occur. We see only exception.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for D3DCREATE_FPU_PRESERVE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172527(v=vs.85).aspx) does say that "*Portions of Direct3D assume floating-point unit exceptions are masked; unmasking these exceptions may result in undefined behavior*". I suppose that means you were lucky in the past; this is one of those cases where "undefined" means "used to work and now doesn't".

[Floating point exceptions](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/FP-Exceptions.html) basically result for any operation that would produce a `NaN` or infinite value from finite values (the most common is division by zero).

If it happens on one driver/GPU combination but not the other, it is likely that the drivers/GPUs are rounding differently in certain corner cases. Keep an eye out for edge values - very small values multiplied by very large ones for instance. For instance (x * 1e10 + y) / 1e10 might result in zero in some scenarios, which could then allow divide by zero errors to creep in. This kind of debugging can be pretty annoying but is part of the reality of dealing with a variety of GPUs.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You're correct about the note in the documentation. However earlier version of this documentation didn't contain this warning. It was added later when our code was mainly done. It's strange that ONE flag adds TWO things - double-preciosion and FPU exceptions. And I have no idea why I need to get FPU exception in the basic function CreateDevice().